# can get out some data from call to a label in cmd file?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, windows-xp, cmd

this example isn't working:

```
call :testcall > %output%
goto :eof

:testcall
  echo return
goto :eof

:eof
```

I need that `%output%` contained `return` string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that you want the text `return` in the variable `output`, not in the file named `output`!?

There are two *common* ways to get this:
`For/F` and `set/p`

```
@echo off
call :testcall > outfile.tmp
< outfile.tmp set /p myVariable=
set myVar
goto :eof

:testcall
  echo return
goto :eof
```

set/p can also read more than one line, when you enclose it into parenthesis

```
@echo off
call :testcall2 > outfile.tmp
< outfile.tmp (
   set /p myVariable1=
   set /p myVariable2=
   set /p myVariable3=
)
set myVar
goto :eof

:testcall
  echo return line1
  echo content2
  echo content3
goto :eof
```

With `For/F` you could also read data into variables, and you don't need any temporary file.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('echo return') DO set myVariable=%%A
set myVar
```

Comment: +1 Now that I see your answer, I think you have the correct interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
(
     call :testcall
) >output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

It works as long as variable `output` is defined properly.

```
@echo off
set output=test.txt
call :testcall > %output%
goto :eof

:testcall
  echo return
goto :eof

:eof
```

***Edit***

I think I may have mis-interpreted the question. I assumed the OP was attempting to create a file. But I believe jeb's answer has the correct interpretation, along with a good answer.